# Create a column with unique values for every unique value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with a column like

```
         Customer  
   0.      ABC     
   1.      ABC     
   2.      DEF     
   3.      GHI     
   4.      JKL     
   5.      JKL
```

I need to add another column so that I have an id per customer like this:

```
         Customer  Id
   0.      ABC     1
   1.      ABC     1
   2.      DEF     2
   3.      GHI     3
   4.      JKL     4
   5.      JKL     4
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Option 1:** You can use `groupby().ngroup()`:

```
df['Id'] = df.groupby('Customer').ngroup()+1
```

**Option 2**: You can also use `rank`:

```
df['Id'] = df['Customer'].rank(method='dense')
```

Output:

```
    Customer  Id
0.0      ABC   1
1.0      ABC   1
2.0      DEF   2
3.0      GHI   3
4.0      JKL   4
5.0      JKL   4
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by converting to a categorical and grabbing the codes:

```
df['Id'] = df['Customer'].astype('categorical').cat.codes + 1
```