# Rename unique values pandas column in ascending order

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks similar to the one below:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'label': [0, 0, 2, 3, 8, 8, 9],
    'value1': [2, 1, 9, 8, 7, 4, 2],
    'value2': [0, 1, 9, 4, 2, 3, 1],
})
>>> df
   label  value1  value2
0      0       2       0
1      0       1       1
2      2       9       9
3      3       8       4
4      8       7       2
5      8       4       3
6      9       2       1
```

Values in the `label` column are not complete (not `range(0, n, 1)`) due to previously slicing. I would like to reorder this label and assign a sequential range of ascending values so that it becomes:

```py
>>> df
   label  value1  value2
0      1       2       0
1      1       1       1
2      2       9       9
3      3       8       4
4      4       7       2
5      4       4       3
6      5       2       1
```

I currently use the code below. Because my real DataFrame has thousands of unique values any suggestions to do this a bit more efficiently (not including looping over every unique value) would be appreciated.

```py
for new_idx, idx in enumerate(df.label.unique()):
     df.loc[df['label'] == idx, ['label']] = new_idx
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58226595/create-a-column-with-unique-values-for-every-unique-value-in-another-column/58226637#58226637) among others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) for improve performance:

```
df['label'] = pd.factorize(df['label'])[0] + 1
print (df)
   label  value1  value2
0      1       2       0
1      1       1       1
2      2       9       9
3      3       8       4
4      4       7       2
5      4       4       3
6      5       2       1
```

Another idea with [`Series.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html):

```
df['label'] = df['label'].rank(method='dense').astype(int)
print (df)
   label  value1  value2
0      1       2       0
1      1       1       1
2      2       9       9
3      3       8       4
4      4       7       2
5      4       4       3
6      5       2       1
```

Working same only of same ordering:

```
#dta changed for see difference
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'label': [0, 10, 10, 3, 8, 8, 9],
    'value1': [2, 1, 9, 8, 7, 4, 2],
    'value2': [0, 1, 9, 4, 2, 3, 1],
})

df['label1'] = pd.factorize(df['label'])[0] + 1
df['label2'] = df['label'].rank(method='dense').astype(int)
print (df)
   label  value1  value2  label1  label2
0      0       2       0       1       1
1     10       1       1       2       5
2     10       9       9       2       5
3      3       8       4       3       2
4      8       7       2       4       3
5      8       4       3       4       3
6      9       2       1       5       4
```

Comment: Learnt a lot from your answer. Just a quick question: In the dataframe you created as an example, `df['label1']` assign 2 for `10s`, but I though `pd.factorize()` gives the codes in an ordering sequence. Since `10` is the biggest number, it should be assigned the biggest code among other `df[label]` values. I'd appreciate if you could explain about this a little.